# I cannot access the myUser data in the PrivateRoute.jsx

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I cannot access the **user** data in my **PrivateRoute** if I type the path in the URL, but, if I click on the Checkout Tab I can access the Checkout Component.
If I click on the Checkout tab I will see the user if I log the **User**, but only while accessing the path http:3000/checkout, it redirects to the home page, why is taking long to get the data via **ContextAPI** or is it something from **auth0**

User_Context.tsx

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-react";
import { IUserState, ImyUser } from "../Enums & Interface/IUserState";

const UserContext = React.createContext({} as IUserState);
export const UserProvider = ({ children }: { children: JSX.Element }) => {
  //Auth Object
  const { loginWithRedirect, logout, user } = useAuth0();

  const [myUser, setMyUser] = useState({} as ImyUser);

  useEffect(() => {
    setMyUser(user as ImyUser);
  }, [user]);

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider
      value={{
        loginWithRedirect,
        logout,
        myUser,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
};
// make sure use
export const useUserContext = () => {
  return useContext(UserContext);
};
```

PrivateRoute.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-react";
// will remove later
import { useUserContext } from "../context/user_context";

const PrivateRoute = ({ children }: { children: JSX.Element }) => {
  const { myUser } = useUserContext();
  // console.log(myUser);
  if (myUser) {
    return children;
  } else {
    return <Navigate to="/" />;
  }
};
export default PrivateRoute;
```

Comment: Is your `PrivateRoute` component rendered inside `UserProvider`?

Comment: Your provider should be at top of all components that should have access to data of this provider. Eg: `<UserProvider> <PrivateRoute /> <UserProvider/>`

Comment: @NoNam4, yes it is under the UserProvider

`{
 path: "/checkout",
 element: (
<PrivateRoute>
<Checkout />
</PrivateRoute>
        ),
      }, `

Comment: I have a little [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/context-smrg6d?file=/src/Test.tsx) of how to use context, perhaps it helps you. Take a look

Comment: @NoNam4, hello again, but sir using memoized vlaues won't trouble the app, as it will be sending the same values for user?

Comment: You need to add all variables that you need updated values inside `useMemo` array or you can just remove `useMemo`, it will work too

Comment: @NoNam4, I did almost the same, but it still redirects when typing the /checkout in the URL bar, but works if I click on the Checkout tab?